# Problem in installing Ubuntu 12 using USB

Tags: installation, boot-failure

I have a Sony laptop (VPCEH25EN) and i am trying to install **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**. I downloaded the iso named "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso". For installing i created a bootable USB using UltraISO.

When i booted the USB it hangs and shows " **Booting from USB** ", I even left it for hours and it didn't moved a bit. When I booted the ISO in Virtual Box, it ran well.

I even used other tools to make a bootable USB, then it says " **BOOTMNGR missing** ".

Please help, I am new to Ubuntu and my optical drive is fried.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Were you able to boot from the pendrive by pressing the f11 key, when the vaio logo showed? ( if so how do you enable it?)

Comment: @ManupalSingh In a vaio the BIOS manager is accessed from F2 key just enable boot from external drives and change the boot sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the bootable USB using [UnetBootIn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

My experience with this program is excellent.

Otherwise if you have another Ubuntu computer you may try "Startup Disk Creator"

Comment: Thanks for the advice but i tried it, it only says "BOOTMNGR MISSING" although I haven't used Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: The "Startup Disk Creator" worked fine but he is asking me these:   Busy Box v 1.8.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5 - 1ubuntu4) build-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of build-in commands                 (initrants) Busy Box v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.118.5-1ubuntu4)multi-call binary. Usage: mount [options] [-o OPTS] DeEVICE NODE   Mount a filesystem.Filesystem autodetection requires /proc.  Option:  ...............                                     These are file system-specific -o flags.                         Can not mount /dev/loop on /cow                                   //info ends here.Please help

Comment: By any chance do you have any other usb devices connected to your computer? Try disconnecting all but the bootable pendrive.

Comment: No other USB device is connected. Thanks for helping is such short notice....

Comment: Bootmgr is Windows bootloader. So it is trying to boot Windows. If you remove the USB drive, does windows boot?

Comment: Yes the windows boots successfully when i remove the USB drive.....

Comment: The installation is complete. Just one has to do is check the option "Discard on shutdown, unless you save them elsewhere" in Startup Disk Creator.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution proposed above (UnetBootIn), downloading Ubuntu via the torrents is often less corrupt than a direct download of a large .iso file. [HERE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) is the link (scroll down to Torrents).

Comment: The copy is running fine in Oracle VM Virtual Machine, it just doesn't boot.